# Use bs4 for webscraping validation

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Not sure why but this code today is not working as expected (I've used other times the same code for different html and worked like a charm).
I am trying to find out if the text "Anular" is in the HTML code. But is always comes as No, when the text is visible there.

Code is:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import re
    html = browser.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    if soup.findAll(text = re.compile('Anular')):
       registo2 = "Yes"
    else:
       registo2 = "No"
```

Html is (part of it):

```
</td>
</tr></tbody></table>
<span class="filter" style="display: block; width: 100%; position: absolute; top:17px;" id="Almoço">
<form action="" method="post" name="itens" id="item_frm">
<input type="hidden" name="item" value="30" /><span style="top: 70px;" class="item_check2">Marcada</span><br /><div style="display:none;z-index:1000;position:fixed;" class="divBlockClass" id="divBlock7172"></div><br /><div style="z-index:10001;" id="msgbox_ref_7172" class="msgbox_ref"><span id="msg_ref_7172"></span><br /><br /><input type="submit" onclick="
                                        document.getElementById('msgbox_ref_7172').style.visibility='hidden'" onmouseout="this.className='input_off'" onmouseover="this.className='input_on'" name="SetData" class="input_off" id="btn_marcar" value="   OK   " /> 
                                        <input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('msgbox_ref_7172').style.visibility='hidden';document.getElementById('divBlock7172').style.display='none'" onmouseout="this.className='input_off'" onmouseover="this.className='input_on'" class="input_off" value="Cancelar" />
                                        </div><br /><span class="itemref_btn">
                                                                        <input type="button" "="" onclick="document.getElementById('marcada').value='true';document.getElementById('divBlock7172').style.display='block'; document.getElementById('msgbox_ref_7172').style.visibility='visible';
                                                                        document.getElementById('msgbox_ref_7172').style.top=event.pageY+'px';
                                                                        document.getElementById('msg_ref_7172').innerHTML='Tem a certeza que deseja anular?';" onmouseout="this.className='input_off'" onmouseover="this.className='input_on'" style="cursor: pointer; width: 112px;" value="Anular Refeição" class="input_off" id="btn_anular_7172" /></span><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="95%;" id="conteudoTabela">
```

Any idea why is not working? Something that could be improved in the regexp?
 Thanks.

Comment: Your import comes after declaration of parser.

Comment: wrong copy paste from the IDLE. Will correct it in a moment. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the html you provided the string you're looking for is contained in the 'value' attribute of the tag.
So your code would be:

```
if soup.find_all(value=re.compile('Anular')):
    registo2 = "Yes"
else:
    registo2 = "No"
```

Or if you want to check for a string in text or attributes you can use a [function](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) in `find_all`.

```
def f(tag):
    return 'Anular' in tag.get('value', '') or 'Anular' in (tag.string or '')

registo2 = "Yes" if soup.find_all(f) else "No"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand now.